# Why does $f(x)=x^{2}$ define an automorphism when $G$ is abelian and has odd order?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that if $x$ and $y$ have both order $2$ this is false. Assume our group has odd order so that this is not trivial. Does it hold?

If not, why is $f(x)=x^{2}$ an automorphism if $G$ is odd, finite and abelian?

Comment: If $|G|=2k+1$, then what is $(x^2)^{k+1}$ and what is $(y^2)^{k+1}$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you should make your title "When does..." or "...in groups of odd order?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is true in groups of odd order. More generally, **if $x,y$ have odd order and $x^2=y^2$ then $x=y$.**

This follows from $x^{2k+1}=e=y^{2l+1}$ then $x^{(2k+1)(2l+1)}=y^{(2k+1)(2l+1)}=e$ and hence 
$$x=x^{(2k+1)(2l+1)+1}=y^{(2k+1)(2l+1)+1}=y$$

Comment: The hypothesis is really hidden (in the middle of your last displayed equation); it might be a good idea to bring it out into the light a bit....

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the group is abelian tells you $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2$.

The fact that the order is odd tells you no element has order $2$, so the function is injective. Since the group is finite the function is bijective, so an automorphism.

Answer (score 0):

In a (not necessarily abelian) finite group $G$ of order $2n+1$, we have that $\forall x \in G x^{2n+1} = e$. Equivalently, $x * (x^n)^2 = e$, or $(x^n)^2 = x^{-1}$. Hence, for any $x \in G$, we have that $\sqrt{x} = x^{-n}$ is the unique "square root" of $x$.

Switching to additive notation, if $G$ is abelian, then the map $x \mapsto 2x$ is a homomorphism. It then follows that if $G$ is an abelian group of order $2n+1$, then that map will in fact be an automorphism with the inverse sending an element $x$ to $-nx$ (which could then also be called "half of $x$", or denoted "$\frac{1}{2}x$" or "$\frac{x}{2}$").

More generally, for any finite abelian group $A$ and any positive integer $n$, the $n$th power map will be an automorphism of $A$ if and only if $n$ is coprime to the order of $A$. In particular, $A$ can be viewed not only as a $\mathbf{Z}/ord(A)\mathbf{Z}$-module but also as a module over the localization of $\mathbf{Z}$ with respect to the multiplicative subset of integers coprime to the order of $A$.